# Why do upvotes kill the tumbleweed badge?

Tags: discussion, tumbleweed-badge

I understand that one of the requirements for the tumbleweed badge is that a question has no upvotes, but why? I can see it as being a kind of consolation badge for those that don't get their questions answered, but surely if people upvote it (therefore showing it as a good question) and it still gets no answers or comments then that's arguably more frustrating!

It seems with the current system that users are punished by not getting the badge for asking a potentially better question, which seems a bit strange to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it's a consolation prize for a user who has asked a question that does badly.  This is not the same as a bad question, which will recieve downvotes, comments and possibly be closed.

Comment: If I ask a question and it receives no answers or comments, but perhaps one upvote, that's in my mind still a question that's done badly!

Comment: @berry120 Sure, it's done badly; but not badly enough to 'earn' a tumbleweed!

Answer (score 1):

A question with no upvotes and no comments and low views is not necessarily bad. If it were bad, it'd surely have received downvotes and comments (and close votes).

If your question is so good that it receives upvotes, comments and views, you're eligible for at least the [Nice Question](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/20/nice-question) and [Popular Question](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/26/popular-question) badges (and if it get better, even the [Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/21/good-question), [Notable Question](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/27/notable-question), [Favorite Question](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/33/favorite-question), [Great Question](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/22/great-question), [Famous Question](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/28/famous-question) and [Stellar Question](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/36/stellar-question) badges). That seems a pretty good "compensation" to me.

Comment: Not necessarily if it's a question in one of those niche tags that generally has low participation rates.

Comment: @Jeff: I understand exactly what you mean (the major part of my answers are in the niche tags). It only requires more time. Much more time.